# Problems installing angular-summernote

Tags: angularjs

I have installed 'summernote' with bower:

```
bower install angular-summernote
```

added the following links to index.html:

```
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
<link href="../bower_components/summernote/dist/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>  
<script src="../bower_components/summernote/dist/summernote.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-summernote/dist/angular-summernote.min.js"</script>
```

If I add the summernote dependency to my app:

```
angular.module('myRecipesApp', ['ui.router','ngResource','summernote'])
```

the screen goes blank.
I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong!

Comment: As from ur post last script tag is not proper, also it will be helpful if you share you console errors.

Comment: Next time please use `--save-dev` with `bower install <package_name>` . eg. `bower install angular-summernote --save-dev`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I closed the tag and it worked. Apologies for the silliness.